# A list of dataframes where column variable type to be changed from character to numeric in R

Tags: r, list, nested, transformation

I have created a nested list of dataframes through read.csv and lapply function. This nested list of data frames contains the first column as `product` and rest 239 columns for data on various countries.
All the numbers are in character format which I wish to convert into numeric form for each dataframe in the list.
I have used the following code. But it removes the `product` column[1] from each dataframe and displays only `[2:240]` rest of the columns. How to prevent the `product` column from getting removed?

```
files <- list.files(path = "D:\\R34\\casia3\\data_kaz\\export\\", pattern = "*.csv")

myfiles <- lapply(files, function(x) {
  df <- read.csv(x, strip.white = T, stringsAsFactors = F, sep = ",")
  df$ID <- as.character(x)
  return(df)
})


myfiles <- lapply(myfiles, function(x) lapply(x[2:240], as.numeric))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `type.convert` to automatically convert the class

```
lstdat <- lapply(lstdat, function(x) {x[] <- lapply(x,
             type.convert, as.is = TRUE); x})
```

Comment: will it handle na.rm or we have to mention this.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
myfiles <- lapply(myfiles, function(x) {x[2:240] <- lapply(x[2:240], as.numeric);x})
```

Since you are applying `as.numeric` function to column `2:240` only those are returned back. We can apply the function to those selected columns and return back the entire dataframe from the inner `lapply` call.

---

If interested you might also consider this `tidyverse` alternative

```
library(tidyverse)
myfiles <- map(myfiles,. %>% mutate_at(2:240, as.numeric))
```

Comment: @ambrishdhaka Sure. `;` is a way to separate two commands in R. The first command changes column 2 to 240 to numeric whereas second command `x` returns the entire changed dataframe back.